# Can not load admin url in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2 with sample data using command line instructions. I can load the frontend without any problem.

When I load admin url, its getting redirected. Actual admin url: local.magento_2.com/admin_1kzjqv/, redirected url: http://local.magento_2.com/admin_1kzjqv/http:/index/local.magento_2.com/admin_1kzjqv/admin/index/index/key/dc29e0deb12bceefaf5d6b01551063e15e66b94a638e3915bf190b9d5d79743f/.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide full command which you use for installing magento2?

Comment: 1. export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/magento2/bin                               2. magento setup:install --base-url=http://local.magento_2.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento_2 --db-user=root --db-password=root123   --admin-firstname=Kelvyn --admin-lastname=Joshua --admin-email=joshuakelvyn@grossmaninteractive.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database --sales-order-increment-prefix="ORD$" --session-save=db --use-rewrites=1                            3.php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: try use protocol in base-url `--base-ur="http://local.magento_2.com"`

Comment: sorry, tried it but not working @Anton Ohorodnyk

Comment: Try changing the base_url to your IP/127.0.01 in DB , I guess It may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. its an url problem. wrong format: http://local.magento_2.com/, correct format: local.magentosample.com. url doesn't save in the correct format in db. so i have changed and it worked fine. thank you guys helping..

Comment: Also, the URL must end in /

Answer (score 3):

clear cache, reindex data in your magento

php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score -1):

I replace this at line 138 and it worked!

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Comment: where is this line 138?